# How to convert String in SQL (ORACLE)

Tags: sql, oracle

I try to select from `table_1` where `ITEM_FIELD_A` is not in `ITEM_FIELD_B`. The Item_FIELD_B value are look as below. I was expecting no `COVER_TAPE` & `SHIPPING_REELS` will be selected. But unfortunately, it's not working.

[image]

**The sql I used to select the table**

```
select * from table_1 where MST.ITEM_FIELD_A not in ITEM_FIELD_B
```

Question:
In Oracle, is there any function to decode the string. so that the above select statement will not return `COVER_TAPE` and `SHIPPING_REELS`??

Comment: I can see syntax error in the select statement?

Comment: Check the INSTR function

Comment: yes. I know the syntax error.. missing the *. but this is not important... @Serpiton.. How to use the INSTR??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `IN` operator would be used when you wish to compare (or negate) one item in a list such as

```
WHERE ITEM_FIELD_A NOT IN ('COVER_TAPE', 'SHIPPING_REELS', '')
```

What you want is the `LIKE` operator:

```
WHERE ITEM_FIELD_B NOT LIKE '%' || ITEM_FIELD_A || '%'
```

Apologies if I got the wildcard wrong, been a while since I last touched Oracle.

Comment: thanks.. i tried this before. but never try to reverse the Item_field_B and Item_field_A position. Awesome!

Comment: Be aware that any string operation is not terribly efficient and `LIKE` will tend to prevent the use of indexes which hinders performance even further so use with caution. Sometimes it's unavoidable though.

Answer (score 0):

Check out below Query:

```
WITH TAB1 AS 
( SELECT 'COVER_TAPE' ITEM_A FROM DUAL 
  UNION
  SELECT 'CARRIER_TAPE' ITEM_A FROM DUAL 
  UNION
  SELECT 'SHIPPING_REELS' ITEM_A FROM DUAL 
),
TAB2 AS
(
  SELECT 'COVER_TAPE,SHIPPING_REELS' ITEM_B FROM DUAL 
)
SELECT ITEM_A, ITEM_B FROM TAB1, TAB2 WHERE INSTR(ITEM_B, ITEM_A) <=0
```

INSTR will return >0 if same sequence of characters is available.

Answer (score 0):

```
SQL> with t(x , y) as
  2  (
  3  select 'A', q'[('A','B','C')]' from dual union all
  4  select 'R', q'[('A','B','C','D')]' from dual union all
  5  select 'C', q'[('A', 'C','D')]' from dual
  6  )
  7  select x, y
  8  from t where y not like q'[%']'||x||q'['%]'
  9  /

X          Y                                                                    
---------- --------------------------------------------------                   
R          ('A','B','C','D')
```